# How do I correct InnoDB Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID?

Tags: mysql, innodb, ubuntu, upgrade, tablespaces

Some time ago after an update of Ubuntu 20.10, I discovered that MySQL was not running. When I tried to restart it, the error message suggested that it had started, failed and stopped. A check of the error log contained "InnoDB Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID" and listed 25 such instances, for example `Tablespace ID: 92 = ['mercury/pickupcity.ibd', 'mycity/wp_mycity_eventlog.ibd']`

How do I correct InnoDB Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID?

Comment: The first visible hint that something was gone awry was when new upgrades ended with a message that MySQL was unable to start an I had no clue it had stopped. Locally hosted Web pages depending on it became inaccessible. I wasn't doing anything related to MySQL when whatever happened.

Comment: It's a MySQL problem, that just happens to be on Ubuntu. I wasn't upgrading the MySQL version. I just accepted a prompt that various upgrades were available and as usual, without checking all the applications being updated, I accepted "Update all".. So now that two files are sharing a table space, whatever caused it. I want to correct fixing the wheel that punctured and not find which hole I fell into. MySQL  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading up on what a tablespace was, it became clear that they were  tables in the databases. I noticed that one database recurred in each of the 25 lines, whether it was first in the order or second. Based on that I concluded that that database was linked to the problem and so deleted it using `sudo rm -R /var/lib/mysql/mercury` in the console.

Next I started MySQL with `sudo systemctl start mysql` and after an unusual delay, the server started.

Luckily I have the sql file to recreate the deleted database.